# how to put widgets like cards that shown in the picture on top of an app bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm beginner in flutter
and i had to do some things that are required
so my question is how I put all of these widgets on top of the app bar widget the output:

[image]

what i want to recreate :

[image]

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Stack widget for that. Stack widget is used to place one widget on top of another.

```
Stack( 
   children: [
      Container(color: Colors.blue),// your blue container here
      Column( //your entire column here
         children: [ .... ], 
      ), 
   ], 
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stack check here the stack official [Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)